# Cannot escape character '@' in fstab file

Tags: fstab, ftp

I want to attach remote FTP directory as a local directory in my system. I will use curlftpfs line in the fstab file , but to login I have to pass my user name and password. The user name has a special character (@) and it needs to be escaped via octal ascii code. The octal ascii for '@' is 100. But when I try to enter the following into the FSTAB file,

```
curlftpfs#myself\100myself.com:ftpPassword@ftp://ftp.mysite.com /mnt/somedir
```

I get an error saying

```
Error connecting to ftp: Couldn't resolve host 'myself.com:ftpPassword@ftp://ftp.mysite.com'
```

The fstab does not recognize escaped symbol @ (\100) and thinks that the FTP site should start immediately after the @ symbol (just like I haven't escaped it).

Can someone help? Why I cannot escape @, when it can be done for space character, for example?

Comment: Um…yeah? That'll happen when you have the username/password before the protocol? Try ```
curlftpfs#ftp://myself\100myself.com:ftpPassword\100ftp.mysite.com /mnt/somedir ```
instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible in fstab file as @ symbol is also a trigger. Experts recommend using SSHFS instead (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS).

I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: SSHFS does not support FTP. it only support SFTP (SFTP is a much better protocol to be sure, but that doesn't help if you're not in control of what protocol the remote server is using)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this another way...  for example

I just added `,credentials=/home/martijn/.smbpass` to my fstab's list of options for the mount in question and in the /home/martijn/.smbpass file I have the following:

```
username=martijn
password=P@ssword
```

the password works that way.

Hope this helps someone.